# mapbox vector tile with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mapbox

Anyone have experience enabling mapbox vector tile for Elastic? I have a v7.15 docker container of Elasticsearch running with basic authentication but getting this error when I try to access to index/_mvt/spatial_field/:z/:x/:y endpoint.

reason": "current license is non-compliant for [geotile_grid aggregation on geo_shape fields]",
"license.expired.feature": "geotile_grid aggregation on geo_shape fields"

How do I enable this feature locally or feed it the right license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed this in my docker environment setting to get a 30 days trial for the geoshape aggregation feature since the basic subscription does not support it.

- "xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial"